# go trough javascript array and get next array index value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array which holds option values from select.

```
var arrValues = new Array();
$("#myId option").each(function()
{
    var sel = $("#myId").val();
    arrValues.push(sel);
}
```

now I want to find current selected value from #myId select option and take next array index value.

forexample
if array contains values like

```
array = "AB", "CD", "EF"
```

if my currently selected value is AB I want to take CD value and store into var nextValue variable.

Comment: You want this to happen every time you select an item from the select drop down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following function returns the next value or an empty string if the current value is the last value:

```
function getNextValue(array, currentValue) {
    var nextValue = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if(array[i] == currentValue) {
            nextValue = array[i + 1];
            break;
        }
    }
    return nextValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it:

[D E M O](http://jsfiddle.net/6zf67/)

```
var curval, nextval, _index, arrValues = new Array();

$(function() { bindDropdown();});
function bindDropdown() {
   $("#myselect option").each(function()
    {
        arrValues.push($(this).val());
    });
    $("#myselect").on('change', function() {
        curval = $( "#myselect" ).val();
        _index = $.inArray(curval, arrValues);
        nextval = arrValues[(_index==arrValues.length-1) ? 0 : _index+1];
    }); 
}
```

**nextval** will be your next value..

**Notice**: if you choose the last option, then your next becomes the first.. I don't know if that's your desired behavior so let me know..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find the index in the array, then just increment it to get the next. Be careful if the last option is selected, because there is no next value.

```
var nextValue;
var index = arrValues.indexOf($('#myId').val());
if(index < arrValues.length-1){
    nextValue = arrValues[index+1];
} else {
    // the selected value is the last in the array so can't get next
}
```